# Handler to show the countdown timer is not reliable

Tags: android

I am developing an App where I show the countdown timer. To countdown the time I am using Handler class. Once the countdown timer reaches certain time the Alarm goes off. My problem is as below,
        Initially I show the timer time as 04:00:00. Once it reaches 00:00:00 then the Alarm goes off. The Alarm code is working fine. But the timer display is not reliable. It works fine until I keep the App open. If I close the App (using Home or Back) or lock the device and open App again then the timer shown is not the correct one (delaying a lot, but still alarm works on-time). (But it works sometimes very fine under the same scenario). But whenever I ping the device to the system for checking the Log in eclipse that time all works fine!!!!!!!

```
 1. I want to know whether I am using the Handler properly or not
 2. (or) Is going out of the App or locking the device causing the problem
```

Below is my Handler code,

Handler digiHandler;

// Method to initialize the time and define the Handler

```
public void initialize(int hourstime,int mintime,int sectime){
    hour = hourstime;
    min = mintime;
    sec = sectime;
    digiHandler = new Handler();
    handleRunnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            updateTimes();
        }
    };
}


public void startUpdateTheread(){
    digiHandler.postDelayed(handleRunnable, UPDATEDELAY);
}       

// Method to update the timer times

private void updateTimes(){

    timerText = String.format(timerFormat,hour,min,sec );
    -------------------------
    -------------------------
    --  code for incrementing the time ---
    --------------------------
    --------------------------
    --------------------------

        startUpdateTheread();           
}
```

Please give the suggestions

Thanks

**Edit:** 
  When I observed the log it shows that to countdown 1 second of timer sometimes it is taking 1 minute time. The log is as below,

09-21 **21:09:18.965**: DEBUG/DigitalTimer(7656): timerText**:**04:22:54**

```
    ****long difference here****
```

09-21 **21:10:19.308**: DEBUG/DigitalTimer(7656): timerText**:**04:22:53**

..................................................................................
..................................................................................
..................................................................................

09-21 **21:10:23.314**: DEBUG/DigitalTimer(7656): timerText**: **04:22:49**

```
    **--long difference here ---**
```

09-21 **21:11:22.604**: DEBUG/DigitalTimer(7656): timerText**:**04:22:48**

It is happening always. So I can rule out that locking/coming out of an App is causing the  problem. Seems I need to tweak the Handler part of the code.

Comment: Why not use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: @Zharf - Thanks for the answer. I will try this CountDownTimer. Please see my Edit point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the activity dies, then so does the thread it spawned, I recommend creating a service to handle this since such timers can be long i imagine (over 4 minutes) and in that time, you need the application to not die.
take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html and let me know if that seems like a good enough solution.